# Select Into x From y error 'from not found where expected'

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This is using oracle 11g:

```
insert into B (table_name, column_name)
  select 
      A.table_name as B.table_name,
      A.column_name as B.column_name
      from A
  where A.table_name = 'example_table' and A.column_name = 'example_column';
```

B has 5 columns, and I'm attempting to insert two of them for a given row when i get an error saying from keyword not found where expected.  I'm at a loss here, most examples for insert into use this structure.

The other 3 columns in table B allow null values so i do not think it should be an issue that i am not providing that data as they will be from other tables.

Comment: Can you post the original code that has the error?  This looks like you've replaced the names of things in the code.

Comment: The columns actually have the same name in both tables, but the table names are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the "B." prefix from the column aliases in the `SELECT` clause, as in:

```
insert into B (table_name, column_name)
  select 
      A.table_name as table_name,
      A.column_name as column_name
      from A
  where A.table_name = 'example_table' and A.column_name = 'example_column';
```

Comment: Or skip the aliases altogether; they're not needed.